TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientModules') when running npm start in Next.js app
I am encountering an issue with my Next.js application. After building the app using npm run build, I try to start it with npm start, but I receive the following error:
⨯ TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientModules')

Steps to reproduce:
Run npm run build to build the Next.js application.
After the build completes successfully, run npm start to start the application.
Error message:
⨯ TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientModules')
Environment:
Node.js version: 18.20.3
npm version: 9.6.7
Next.js version: 14.2.4
Operating System: windows-11
What I've tried:
i am tried reinstalling the packages
